# Is it a good design to define all events in the entrance UI?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from a official sample [project.](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/StateCodelab/finished/src/main/java/com/codelabs/state/todo/TodoScreen.kt)

1: The author define all events such as `onAddItem`, `onRemoveItem` ... in the entrance UI `fun TodoScreen`, is it a good design?

2: You know the `fun TodoScree` will become huge when the functionality of the APP is increased, how can I improve the app architecture ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun TodoScreen(
    items: List<TodoItem>,
    currentlyEditing: TodoItem?,
    onAddItem: (TodoItem) -> Unit,
    onRemoveItem: (TodoItem) -> Unit,
    onStartEdit: (TodoItem) -> Unit,
    onEditItemChange: (TodoItem) -> Unit,
    onEditDone: () -> Unit
) {
   ...
}


class TodoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val todoViewModel by viewModels<TodoViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            StateCodelabTheme {
                Surface {
                    TodoActivityScreen(todoViewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun TodoActivityScreen(todoViewModel: TodoViewModel) {
    TodoScreen(
        items = todoViewModel.todoItems,
        currentlyEditing = todoViewModel.currentEditItem,
        onAddItem = todoViewModel::addItem,
        onRemoveItem = todoViewModel::removeItem,
        onStartEdit = todoViewModel::onEditItemSelected,
        onEditItemChange = todoViewModel::onEditItemChange,
        onEditDone = todoViewModel::onEditDone
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design pattern is called state hoisting, and is explained in the docs:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting

> State hoisting in Compose is a pattern of moving state to a
> composable's caller to make a composable stateless.  State that is
> hoisted this way has some important properties:
>
> - Single source of truth: By moving state instead of duplicating it, we're ensuring there's only one source of truth. This helps avoid
>   bugs. Encapsulated: Only stateful composables will be able to modify
>   their state. It's completely internal.
> - Shareable: Hoisted state can be shared with multiple composables. Say we wanted to name in a different composable, hoisting would allow
>   us to do that.
> - Interceptable: callers to the stateless composables can decide to ignore or modify events before changing the state.
> - Decoupled: the state for the stateless ExpandingCard may be stored anywhere. For example, it's now possible to move name into a
>   ViewModel.

---

About the issue with "my screen constructor is gonna be huge".

For lower level components i like to follow the pattern described in this compose tutorial: https://youtu.be/SMOhl9RK0BA?t=546 : don't pass five different text with five onClickLambdas for five different buttons to a component, just pass in a list of 5 Buttons

For higher level components i like to make sure i only pass high level stuff, and let the composable figure out the low level things.

Comment: Thanks! But it's not a good project architecture.